# How to detect if a point is contained within a bounding rect - opecv & python

Tags: python, opencv, bounding-box

I have a set of points [(x0,y0), (x1,y1), .. ]

And a set of bounding rectangles produced using the `cv2.boundingRect(someContour)` function.
Where each bounding box is an iterable object with four coordinates `(a,b,c,d)`.
My questions are:

1. what is the meaning of these four numbers?.
2. how to check if each given point is contained within the bounding rect?

I know that opencv for C++ has the 'contains' method but it doesnt exist for python.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. a,b are the top-left coordinate of the rectangle and (c,d) be its width and height.
   [OpenCV Contour Features](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html)
2. to judge a point(x0,y0) is in the rectangle, just to check if a < x0 < a+c and b < y0 < b + d

Comment: Thanks a lot! very helpful!

Comment: @AlanKazbekov the question is tagged `python` and the python bindings don't support the Rect class

Comment: @Hooting this actually incorrect since OpenCV rectangles are _inclusive_ with respect to left and top edges, so the code should be `a <= x0 < a+c and b <= y0 < b + d`. See https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html#details

Answer (score 7):

```
def rectContains(rect,pt):
    logic = rect[0] < pt[0] < rect[0]+rect[2] and rect[1] < pt[1] < rect[1]+rect[3]
    return logic

rect = (a,b,c,d)

rectContains(rect,pt)
```