# Geting image descriptors for an image patch

Tags: c++, opencv, sift

I have already detected and computed SIFT keypoints and descriptors in an image (which I need for a different purpose) with OpenCV (4.3.0-dev).

```cpp
Mat descriptors;
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
sift->detectAndCompute(image, Mat(), keypoints, descriptors);
```

Now I want to get keypoints and descriptors for a rectangular patch of this same image (from the previously extracted keypoints and descriptors)  and do so without having to run the costly `detectAndCompute()` again. The only solutions I can come up with are masking and region of interest extraction, both of which require `detectAndCompute()` to be run again. How can this be done?

Comment: so from your already computed keypoints you want to identify all which are in some roi? Or do you want different keypoints (e.g. different sift parameters)?

Comment: @Micka the former. I was hoping this would be evident enough from my question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065834/how-to-detect-if-a-point-is-contained-within-a-bounding-rect-opecv-python

Comment: @Micka I do have an idea of how I could get the relevant key points. But then I need to `compute()` the descriptors which is quite costly as well. I was hoping that there is a way to take a part of the already computed descriptors but how to do that is not apparent to me.

Comment: you do have a list with all already computed keypoints and descriptors. Just add the wanted ones to a new empty list.